# How can I get SQL AdmitDate and DischargeDate with specific events?

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table for homecare system and I have a series of entry logs for customer. I want to get a specific output. I want to break it down by record type 'expired', 'Discharge' and 'Discharge-Returning'.
if there is Admit and return events for a customer but there is no expired, discharge or discharge-returning event for that customer in between admit and return events then I want min admit date for that customer. If there is admit date or return date and no discharge event for that customer  then I want to add 12/31/9999 showing that he is still in the location. please see how I want an output data below. I have added 4 customer data.

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[homecare](
    [Location] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Customer] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [recordtype] Varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO



  INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/20/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/21/2019','InfoUpdate');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/22/2019','Therapy');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/29/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/30/2019','Therapy');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '4/1/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '4/5/2019','Expired');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (101, 34567, '3/27/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 56787, '4/5/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 56787, '4/9/2019','Expired');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '3/30/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '3/31/2019','Infochange');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '4/1/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/2/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/12/2019','Discharge-Returning');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/17/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/30/2019','Discharge-Returning');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '6/8/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '8/10/2010','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '11/3/2010','Discharge-Returning');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/01/2010','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/8/2010','Hospital');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/12/2010','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/18/2010','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/01/2010','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/03/2012','Therapy');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/07/2012','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/10/2012','Hospital');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/12/2012','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/17/2012','Discharge');
```

Output:-

```
Location Customer AdmitDate AdmitStatus   DischargeDate DischargeStatus
100       45454   3/20/2019 Admit         4/5/2019       Expired
101       34567   3/27/2019 Admit         12/31/9999     Still in the location
100       56787    4/5/2019 Admit          4/9/2019      Expired
102       76567   3/30/2019 Admit          4/1/2019      Discharge
102       76567   5/2/2019  Admit          5/12/2019     Discharge-Returning
102       76567   5/17/2019 Return         5/30/2019     Discharge-Returning
102       76567   6/8/2019 Return          12/31/9999    Still in the location
100      43408    8/10/2010 Admit          11/3/2010      Discharge-Returning
100      43408    12/01/2010 Return        12/18/2010     Discharge
100      45090    09/01/2012  Admit        09/17/2012     Discharge
```

My New dataset is below.  Now, I have converted all Return into "Admit" and Discharge, Discharge-Returning and Expired events into "Discharge" events. My new Dataset is as below. This would solve my entire dataset. Can someone resolve the query?

```
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/20/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/21/2019','Admit'); 
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/22/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/22/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/30/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '4/1/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '4/5/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (101, 42000, '4/9/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '3/19/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '5/21/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '5/25/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '5/25/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 44000, '5/20/2019','Admit');
```

Desired Output:-

```
Location Customer AdmitDate AdmitStatus   DischargeDate DischargeStatus
100       42000   3/20/2019 Admit         3/22/2019       Discharge
101       42000   3/22/2019 Admit         4/5/2019       Discharge
100       42000    4/9/2019 Admit          12/31/9999      Still in the location
100       43000   3/19/2019 Admit          5/25/2019      Discharge
102       44000   5/20/2019  Admit          12/31/9999      Still in the location
```

Comment: @Gordon, I have added the customer 43408. It's a unique situation. He returned on 12/01/2010 and then went to hospital and then returned back and then discharged. So I want output as 12/01/2010 to 12/18/2010. the current query is giving output as 12/01/2010 to 9999-12-31 and 12/12/2010 to 12/18/2010. Can you assist?

Comment: When there is more than 2 returns in between two 'Discharge', 'Expired', or 'Discharge-Returning' event then I want to use the min return date followed by the DischargeDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

This is tricky.  The first piece is figuring out where the "stays" start.  Obviously "admin" is one, but then you need special logic for the returns.  The following query compares the date of the previous "admin" and "exit" status to determine if a "return" is the start of a new row.

After that, it is cumbersome aggregation:

```
with hc as (
      select hc.*,
             sum(case when recordtype = 'Admit' or
                           recordtype = 'Return' and prev_admit_end > prev_admit
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by customer, location order by date) as grp
      from (select hc.*,
                   max(case when recordtype = 'Admit' then date end) over (partition by customer, location order by date) as prev_admit,
                   max(case when recordtype in ('Discharge', 'Expired', 'Discharge-Returning') then date end) over (partition by customer, location order by date) as prev_admit_end
            from homecare hc
           ) hc
     )
select location, customer,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then recordtype end) as admit_status,
       min(date) as admit_date,
       (case when max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then recordtype end) in ('Discharge', 'Expired', 'Discharge-Returning')
             then max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then recordtype end) 
             else 'Still in the location'
        end) as discharge_date,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then recordtype end) as discharge_status,
       (case when max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then recordtype end) in ('Discharge', 'Expired', 'Discharge-Returning')
             then max(date) else '9999-12-31'
        end) as discharge_date
from (select hc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location, customer, grp order by date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by location, customer, grp order by date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from hc
     ) hc
group by grp, location, customer
order by min(date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4eddc98d5801fcbce542d416a9f58971) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I have tested the query on my dataset and it works perfectly. Great to see the solution.

Comment: @ChetuP , This query returns 3 rows for customer 43408 while the requested result is two rows with different values. The solution which I gave you at Microsoft QnA forums provide the exact result which you asked for. Check and compare and confirm.

Comment: The above query provides the result for the first dataset. my new dataset is different and I want to solve that dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the behaviour of 'return' as a recordtype/AdmitStatus.
For Customer 76567 it is used to indicate a form of admission where as for 45454 it is used to denote return from Therapy. Therefore below Therapy is indicative of Customers leaving and the return behaves as a return. If Return does behave as either a readmission or just a comment let me know and I'll update/delete my answer.

```
WITH Homecare AS (
    Select 
        RN = row_number() over (partition by Customer order by date asc),
        Location, 
        Customer, 
        Date as AdmitDate, 
        recordtype as AdmitStatus 
    from [dbo].[homecare] 
    WHERE recordtype in ('Admit','Return','Expired','Therapy','Discharge','Discharge-Returning')
    --AND Customer in ( Select Customer, recordtype from dbo.Homecare group by Customer, recordtype ))
),
HomecareEx as (
select h.*, 
    lead(h.AdmitDate,1,'12/31/9999') over (partition by h.customer order by h.AdmitDate) as DischargeDate, 
    lead(h.AdmitStatus,1,'Still in Location') over (partition by h.customer order by h.AdmitDate) as DischargeStatus
from Homecare h --Where h.AdmitStatus in ('Admit','Return')
) --select * from HomecareEx
select Location, 
    Customer, 
    AdmitDate, 
    AdmitStatus, 
    DischargeDate,
    DischargeStatus
from HomecareEx 
WHERE Coalesce(DischargeStatus,'Still in Location') not in ('Admit','Return') 
AND AdmitStatus in ('Admit','Return');
```

Code returns this, not quite what you wanted but it does depend on the behaviour of 'Return'.

| Location | Customer | AdmitDate | AdmitStatus | DischargeDate | DischargeStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 34567 | 2019-03-27 | Admit | 9999-12-31 | Still in Location |
| 100 | 45454 | 2019-03-20 | Admit | 2019-03-22 | Therapy |
| 100 | 45454 | 2019-03-29 | Return | 2019-03-30 | Therapy |
| 100 | 45454 | 2019-04-01 | Return | 2019-04-05 | Expired |
| 100 | 56787 | 2019-04-05 | Admit | 2019-04-09 | Expired |
| 102 | 76567 | 2019-03-30 | Admit | 2019-04-01 | Discharge |
| 102 | 76567 | 2019-05-02 | Admit | 2019-05-12 | Discharge-Returning |
| 102 | 76567 | 2019-05-17 | Return | 2019-05-30 | Discharge-Returning |
| 102 | 76567 | 2019-06-08 | Return | 9999-12-31 | Still in Location |

Comment: Nice to see another solution. Actually, When the customer is on therapy and he returns back. It's not considered a new length of stay. it is only considered when he/she has a status of Discharge, Expired, Discharge-Returning. So for customer 45454, it should not be Admit and Therapy. During therapy he is not leaving the location. The discharge means he is out of location and discharge-returning means he may return in the future. it could clarify what you can think of.