# List of Events Admit and Discharge Date for a specific entry log table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for homecare system and I have a series of entry logs for customer. I want to get a specific output. I want to break it down by record type 'expired', 'Discharge' and 'Discharge-Returning'.

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[homecare](
    [Location] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Customer] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [recordtype] Varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/20/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/21/2019','InfoUpdate');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/22/2019','Therapy');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/29/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/30/2019','Therapy');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '4/1/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '4/5/2019','Expired');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (101, 34567, '3/27/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 56787, '4/5/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 56787, '4/9/2019','Expired');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '3/30/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '3/31/2019','Infochange');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '4/1/2019','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/2/2019','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/12/2019','Discharge-Returning');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/17/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/30/2019','Discharge-Returning');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '6/8/2019','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '8/10/2010','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '11/3/2010','Discharge-Returning');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/01/2010','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/8/2010','Hospital');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/12/2010','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/18/2010','Discharge');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/01/2010','Admit');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/03/2012','Therapy');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/07/2012','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/10/2012','Hospital');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/12/2012','Return');
INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/17/2012','Discharge');
```

Output:-

```
Location Customer AdmitDate AdmitStatus   DischargeDate DischargeStatus
100       45454   3/20/2019 Admit         4/5/2019       Expired
101       34567   3/27/2019 Admit         12/31/9999     Still in the location
100       56787    4/5/2019 Admit          4/9/2019      Expired
102       76567   3/30/2019 Admit          4/1/2019      Discharge
102       76567   5/2/2019  Admit          5/12/2019     Discharge-Returning
102       76567   5/17/2019 Return         5/30/2019     Discharge-Returning
102       76567   6/8/2019 Return          12/31/9999    Still in the location
100      43408    8/10/2010 Admit          11/3/2010      Discharge-Returning
100      43408    12/01/2010 Return        12/18/2010     Discharge
100      45090    09/01/2012  Admit        09/17/2012     Discharge
```

Now, I have converted all Return into "Admit" and Discharge, Discharge-Returning and Expired events into "Discharge" events. My new Dataset is as below. This would solve my entire dataset. Can someone resolve the query?

```
 INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/20/2019','Admit');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/21/2019','Admit'); 
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/22/2019','Discharge');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/22/2019','Admit');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '3/30/2019','Admit');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '4/1/2019','Discharge');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 42000, '4/5/2019','Discharge');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (101, 42000, '4/9/2019','Admit');
    
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '3/19/2019','Admit');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '5/21/2019','Admit');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '5/25/2019','Discharge');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43000, '5/25/2019','Discharge');
    INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 44000, '5/20/2019','Admit');
```

Desired Output:-

```
Location Customer AdmitDate AdmitStatus   DischargeDate DischargeStatus
100       42000   3/20/2019 Admit         3/22/2019       Discharge
101       42000   3/22/2019 Admit         4/5/2019       Discharge
100       42000    4/9/2019 Admit          12/31/9999      Still in the location
100       43000   3/19/2019 Admit          5/25/2019      Discharge
102       44000   5/20/2019  Admit          12/31/9999      Still in the location
```

Comment: Well what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Furthermore, your output appears to be missing scenarios. Customer 45454 has a Return status in your list of population values, but there is no Return row for this customer in your output. Does a Return only show when the customer also has a status of Discharge-Returning?

Comment: How is this question different to [this other one of you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665039/how-can-i-get-sql-admitdate-and-dischargedate-with-specific-events)?

Comment: the return will only show in the output admitstatus when the customer has status of Discharge or Discharge-Returning. as soon as customer has discharge or Discharge-returning then anydate start after that will be considered Admitstatus wheather it is Admit or return. you can see in my output.

Comment: The question is similar but it does not resolve with the query.

Comment: @ChetuP thanks for creating such great scenario. This question deserves upvote not down one.

Comment: I did not downvoted. I am not sure how it was downvoted. I do not do that. I appreciate every small help.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes your query:

**Schema:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[homecare](
>     [Location] [int] NOT NULL,
>     [Customer] INT NOT NULL,
>     [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
>     [recordtype] Varchar(50) NOT NULL
> )
>
>
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/20/2019','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/21/2019','InfoUpdate');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/22/2019','Therapy');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/29/2019','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '3/30/2019','Therapy');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '4/1/2019','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45454, '4/5/2019','Expired');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (101, 34567, '3/27/2019','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 56787, '4/5/2019','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 56787, '4/9/2019','Expired');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '3/30/2019','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '3/31/2019','Infochange');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '4/1/2019','Discharge');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/2/2019','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/12/2019','Discharge-Returning');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/17/2019','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '5/30/2019','Discharge-Returning');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (102, 76567, '6/8/2019','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '8/10/2010','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '11/3/2010','Discharge-Returning');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/01/2010','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/8/2010','Hospital');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/12/2010','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 43408, '12/18/2010','Discharge');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/01/2010','Admit');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/03/2012','Therapy');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/07/2012','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/10/2012','Hospital');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/12/2012','Return');
> INSERT INTO homecare VALUES (100, 45090, '09/17/2012','Discharge');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> with cte as (select *,row_number()over (partition by location ,customer order by date desc)rn,
>  max(case when recordtype  in ('Admit','Return') then date end )
>  over(partition by location, customer order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  AdmitDate,
>  max(case when recordtype  in ('Admit','Return') then recordtype end )
>  over(partition by location, customer order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  AdmitStatus
>  
>
> from homecare hc
> where not exists(select * from homecare h where h.location=hc.location 
> and h.customer=hc.customer and h.date<hc.date and  hc.recordtype='Return' and h.recordtype in ('Therapy','Hospital'))),
> finalCTE as (
> select location,customer,
> admitdate,AdmitStatus,(case when recordtype in ('Admit','Return') then '12/31/9999' else date End)DischargeDate,
> (case when recordtype in ('Admit','Return') then 'Still in Location' else recordtype End)DischargeStatus  from cte where rn=1
> or recordtype in ('expired', 'Discharge' , 'Discharge-Returning') )
> select location,customer,admitdate,AdmitStatus,DischargeDate,DischargeStatus from finalcte
> ```

**Output:**

> | location | customer | admitdate | AdmitStatus | DischargeDate | DischargeStatus |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 43408 | 2010-08-10 | Admit | 2010-11-03 | Discharge-Returning |
> | 100 | 43408 | 2010-12-01 | Return | 2010-12-18 | Discharge |
> | 100 | 45090 | 2010-09-01 | Admit | 2012-09-17 | Discharge |
> | 100 | 45454 | 2019-03-20 | Admit | 2019-04-05 | Expired |
> | 100 | 56787 | 2019-04-05 | Admit | 2019-04-09 | Expired |
> | 101 | 34567 | 2019-03-27 | Admit | 9999-12-31 | Still in Location |
> | 102 | 76567 | 2019-03-30 | Admit | 2019-04-01 | Discharge |
> | 102 | 76567 | 2019-05-02 | Admit | 2019-05-12 | Discharge-Returning |
> | 102 | 76567 | 2019-05-17 | Return | 2019-05-30 | Discharge-Returning |
> | 102 | 76567 | 2019-06-08 | Return | 9999-12-31 | Still in Location |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4331bd9c6e516f676bfd909e753c4bfe)*

Comment: No problem at att. I just wanted to know the reason. Is your problem resolved? Please let me know if you are facing any more difficulties.

Comment: Hi, My problem has not resolved. I tested your query. I will provide sample data where the query is not working. I will post it soon.

Comment: I had posted the similar question on msdn and this query is working great. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/321312/sql-admit-and-discharge-events.html?childToView=321547#answer-321547

Comment: @chetu p please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230140/discussion-between-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-and-chetu-p).